# selectize - shiny, action for multiple choices

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

still learning how to use Shiny/R, sorry if the answer is obvious
trying to cast on the map various layers based on selectize choices (multiple)
So i got:

```
selectizeInput('bays', 'Select rough bay outlines',  
 choices = list("Residents" = "residents", `Pay to park` = "ptp", 
 "Shared use" = "shared"), multiple = TRUE)
```

Every equivalent is a `geojson` file that should be used for the map (here "residents", but of course it populates with a selected option from the selectize input):

```
topoData <- readLines("residents.geojson", warn = FALSE) 
%>% paste(collapse = "\n")

leafletProxy("mymap") %>%
addPolylines(topodata)
```

how can i construct the `observeEvent(input$bays,...)` so every choice triggers the action above (with the right geojson file of course)? I can do it for a single choice but a multiple choice might call for another way. And would it be more effective to use a `submit` button or react to actions? Please note that it can be either adding or removing value from the selectize list? And finally there is a cool gadget in selectize - plugin "remove_button" - adding the entries with a little marker to remove the item - i have seen it for javascript but not for shiny - is it possible somehow?

```
$('#input-tags3').selectize({
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    create: function(input) {
        return {
            value: input,
            text: input
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want an `observeEvent` but a `reactive`. Something like this should work:

```
# server
topoData <- reactive(
paste(
lapply(
paste0(input$bays,".geojson"), function(geojson) {
readLines(geojson)
}
),collapse="\n")
)



leafletProxy %>% addPolyLines(topoData())
```

`input$bays` is a vector of the selected geojson files, and it is reactive so as people change the selectize input the value updates in the server inside of reactive statements (and observe statements).

`topoData` is a reactive the returns the geojson files that are selected. If I understand correctly you just went to paste the different files on top of each into a single character. The `leafletProxy` may have to go inside an `observe`, I'm not sure.

Comment: thanks a lot, will check it tonight, do you happen to have any idea how to apply different colours? a switch inside the reactive? or a switch outside? or maybe something else?